# Byobu keybindings toggle not working

Tags: command-line, 20.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, byobu

I'm a user of Byobu and Midnight Commander. Hence, I liked the option of disable/enable Byobu key bindings with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>, but it doesn't work any more. I don't have any other key binding in this combination (checked with `gsettings list-recursively`).

Besides, command `byobu-keybindings`  doesn't work either. And the result of applying the command is always `ON`:

```
❯ byobu-keybindings
Byobu keybindings: [ON]
❯ byobu-keybindings
Byobu keybindings: [ON]
❯ byobu-keybindings
Byobu keybindings: [ON]
```

I was expecting a toggle behaviour ON/OFF.

**How can recover the usage of <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> or at least `byobu-keybindings`?**

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a glitch. Checking the code of `byobu-keybindings`, it greps for `f-keys.tmux.disable ;`. If you remove the extra  `;` then it works like you would expect (it toggles the keybindings on and off).